# Teradata SQL Same Day Prior Year in same Week

Tags: sql, teradata

Need help figuring out how to determine if the date is the same 'day' as today in teradata.  IE, today `12/1/15 Tuesday`, same day last year was actually `12/2/2014 Tuesday`.

I tried using `current_date - INTERVAL'1'Year` but it returns `12/1/2014`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of math if you can convert your current date's "Day of the week" to a number, and the previous year's "Day of the week" to a number.

In order to do this in Teradata your best bet is to utilize the `sys_calendar.calendar` table. Specifically the `day_of_week` column. Although there are [other ways](http://teradatadba.blogspot.com/2010/04/day-of-week-sql.html) to do it.

Furthermore, instead of using `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR`, it's a good idea to use `ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12)` since `INTERVAL` arithmetic will fail on `2012-02-29` and other Feb 29th leap year dates.

So, putting it together you get what you need with:

```
SELECT  
    ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12)
        +
        (
            (SELECT day_of_week FROM sys_calendar.calendar WHERE calendar_date = CURRENT_DATE)
            -
            (SELECT day_of_week FROM sys_calendar.calendar WHERE calendar_date = ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12))
        )
```

This is basically saying: Take the current dates day of week number (3) and subtract from it last years day of week number (2) to get 1. Add that to last year's date and you'll have the same day of the week as current date.

I tested this for all dates between `01/01/2010` and `CURRENT_DATE` and it worked as expected.

Comment: thanks, i was really most concerned with the 2/29 date so i couldn't straight up use the current_date - 364 logic.

Comment: Honestly, subtracting 52 weeks works just as well here. That's essentially what this is doing in it's round about way and you don't get hit with extra I/O and CPU overhead since it's less math, conversion, and tables.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply subtract 52 weeks?

```
current_date - 364
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below will get you to the abbreviated name for the day of week, it's cumbersome but it works across versions of Teradata.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12) AS DATE FORMAT 'E3') AS CHAR(3)) AS LY_DayOfWeek
     , CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE) AS DATE FORMAT 'E3') AS CHAR(3)) AS CY_DayOfWeek
```

Dates are internally represented at integers in Teradata as `(Year-1900) * 100000 + (MONTH * 100) + DAY`. You may be able to do some creative arithmetic to figure out that 12/1/2015 Tuesday was 12/2/2014 Tuesday last year.